# prevent android service sleep when lock

Tags: android, android-service

Im developing a small APP using cordova, but because the limitations of the webview I need to use socket.io conection in native java.

I make a plugin, and the plugin start a service, this service for now have a timer using vibrate API to make the phone vibrate every second to test, here is my code:

```
public class SamplePlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    private static final String TAG = "SamplePlugin";
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    public Context context;

    @Override
    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);
        // your init code here


        context = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));

    }
}
```

Now my Service example:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

   private static final String TAG = "MyService";
   private static Timer timer = new Timer(); 
   private Context ctx;
   private PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
   private PowerManager pm;


   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        ctx = this;

            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
         PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
         wl.acquire();

      // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
      Log.i(TAG, "START SERVICE");
      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new mainTask(ctx), 0, 1000);
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return START_NOT_STICKY;
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      Log.i(TAG, "STOP SERVICE");
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

    private class mainTask extends TimerTask { 

    private Context context;

        public mainTask(Context context) {
            this.context=context;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "SERVICE TICK");
            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            v.vibrate(200);
        }
    }    


}
```

But when I unplug the USB from the phone and lock my screen, in arround 10 seconds the vibration stops, if I active the screen again or plug a cable, the vibration return, but if I lock without the USB or charger in 10 seconds vibration stops, like the system shutdown the apps.

You can se I try some thing, get a wakelock (try with Full, Partial ans Screen), but at the 10 seconds locked vibration stop.

Try to put the service in STICKY, and the service run inclusive if you close the APP from the APP list! But when lock screen, ~10 seconds and stop...

The one thing I see is, I start the service in the Plugin context, but i think this is no the problem (because in STICKY run with the APP closed)

Its possible, keep the service running in background always? Its a limitation of android systems? (I Nexus 5 rooted with Android 6.0)

Thanks for all help!

Comment: how about using alarm manager? services may be killed by OS if it requires more resources

Comment: But i dont want send notifications to the user, i want to let a socket connection alive to another things

Comment: alarm manager doesn't send notification to the user, consider them as scheduled tasks

Comment: But this allow me only to star a service again every X time, but if my service is stopped the socket is closed, i can change the code to allow connect and reconnect when stop and restart but, this is like a "patch", is not possible let the service running infinite?

Comment: If you wqnt to keep your service active, you should define it as foreground service, but that has many drawbacks regarding resource management. About keeping socket active just imagine how much power the radio will consume

Comment: I try to star the service as a foreground setting in the service the notification and call startForeground(), but nothing.. at 10 seconds stop the vibration.. how do it wassap and services running in background like music players? with the alarm manager every X seconds?